SGE: submitting jobs from frontend to compute nodes are not working
I am trying to submit an mpi job from debain based SGE frontend to compute nodes. Compute nodes doesn't run the job,  error message is "doesnt have an input". But i have an input on the frontend directory /home/<user>/Desktop/.
I have compiled the same code on every compute node having similar directory.
Why Sge is not automatically sharing the input file to the compute node?
Is that some kind of sharing or nfs-server issue?
I have submitted the job from a script by qsub.
